# Is it possible to pass a variable from start_requests() to parse() for each individual request?

Tags: scrapy

I'm using a loop to generate my requests inside `start_request()` and I'd like to pass the index to `parse()` so it can store it in the item. However when I use `self.i` the output has the `i` max value (last loop turn) for every items. I can use `response.url.re('regex to extract the index')` but I wonder if there is a clean way to pass a variable from start_requests to parse.

Answer (score 58):

You can use `scrapy.Request` `meta` attribute:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [...]
        for index, url in enumerate(urls):
            yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'index':index})

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        print(response.meta['index'])
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me, now i can create dynamic csv files to store data.

Answer (score 9):

You can pass `cb_kwargs` argument to `scrapy.Request()`

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [...]
        for index, url in enumerate(urls):
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs={'index':index})

    def parse(self, response, index):
        pass
```