# Invoke a different Spider after page is parsed on another Spider

Tags: scrapy

This has been addressed to some extent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585281/passing-a-request-to-a-different-spider) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401824/pass-scraped-urls-from-one-spider-to-another)

But I'd like to ask here before doing any of what's suggested there because I don't really like any of the approaches.

So basically, I'm trying to **scrape** Steam games. As you may know, Steam has a link where you can access the whole reviews for a game, an example:

https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/reviews/?browsefilter=toprated&snr=1_5_100010_

You can ignore snr and browsefilter query params there.

Anyhow, I have created a single Spider that will crawl the list of games here and works pretty well:

https://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Released_DESC

But now, for each game I want to retrieve all reviews.

Originally I created a new Spider that deals with the infinte scroll in the page that has the whole set of reviews for a game, but obviously that spider needs the URL where those reviews live.

So basically what I'm doing now is **scrape** all games pages and store the URL with reviews for each game in a txt file that is then passed as parameter to the second spider. But I don't like this because it forces me to do a 2-step process and besides, I need to map the results of the second spider to the results of the first one somehow (this reviews belong to this game, etc)

So my questions are:

- Would it be best to send the results of **scraping** the game page (and thus the URL with All reviews) to the second spider, or at least the URL and then fetch all reviews for each game using the second spider? This will be O(N*M) in terms of performance, being N number of games and M number of reviews per game, maybe just because of this, having 2 spiders is worth it...thoughts?
- Can I actually invoke a Spider from another Spider? From what I've read in Scrapy documentation, doesn't look like it. I can probably move everything to one spider but will look awful and it doesn't adhere to the single-responsability principle...

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a different parse procedure?

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#more-examples-and-patterns

```
def parse(self, response):
    # follow links to author pages
    for href in response.css('.author + a::attr(href)'):
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse_author)

    # follow pagination links
    for href in response.css('li.next a::attr(href)'):
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

def parse_author(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).get(default='').strip()

    yield {
        'name': extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text'),
        'birthdate': extract_with_css('.author-born-date::text'),
        'bio': extract_with_css('.author-description::text'),
    }

    # follow pagination links
    for href in response.css('li.next a::attr(href)'):
       yield response.follow(href, self.parse_author)
```

And add the needed values with the meta tag:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta

example in 
[Is it possible to pass a variable from start_requests() to parse() for each individual request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414528/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-variable-from-start-requests-to-parse-for-each-indi)

Comment: Hmmm, keep in mind that retrieving reviews will require several requests, that's why I created a different Spider just for it, so I can parse the results of each infinite scroll result...how would this apply in that case?

Comment: The looping through the endless scroll is done in the 2nd parce procedure. At the end you do the same self call as done in parse "follow pagination links".

Comment: Honestly I don't see how you would iterate over the review pages without a Spider? Unless I would do a loop on that second parse method and replicate what the start_requests, parse does on a Spider...is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: I've added the pagination in the 2nd parse procedure

Comment: I don't think that will work for my case, I get the next page calling a Form for reviews, I don't have the link to the next page when parsing reviews, it's an infinite scroll...